# looptools bridge not working correctly and i do not know what to do

Tags: modeling, selection-tools, loop

[image]

i dont know it is not brigding, please help, in theory just selecting two loops and loop tools bridge could create faces and join structures, not happening.

[image]

Comment: You can only use Bridge Edge Loops if all the edges are part of a single object. You have two seperate objects selected in your image and are trying to bridge edges from each of them which won't work. Even if you used Ctrl-J to join them into one object the bridge will be very messy as you have two edges on the ring which have no vertices along them while the hole in the other object has vertices all round it plus the fact that the hole is offset in the face of the cylinder object.

Comment: Incidentally your question has nothing to do with shape keys so I've no idea why you've used that tag for it!

Comment: how can i solve it? ok thanks will correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is not perfect, but hopefully it helps you:

1. join the two objects as John wrote
2. Select these 2 vertices here:

[image]

Press F

[image]

3. select these 2 vertices with shift-select:

[image]

4. press F

[image]

5. deselect these 2 vertices with shift-select

[image]

6. now press F as long as you like the result

[image]

hope it helps.

Comment: Once the objects are joined Bridge Edge Loops will work once you've selected all the verts round each hole, but as I said the result will be very messy. It really needs the topology of both objects to be re-thought.

Comment: thanks, works like a charm, upvoted and marked